# Django - Looping over unique model field in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a model which a choice field, `category`, which the user must enter when submitting an entry. I would like to create a view in which each category has its own heading (only once), therefore each unique category would have its own heading, and then display the `title` associated to each category.

models.py

```
class Position(models.Model):
    club_functions = Choices('Corporate Relations', 'Events & Conference', 'Marketing & Operations', 'Software Development', 'Product')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.CharField(choices=club_functions, max_length=30, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    spec_q1 = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    spec_q2 = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

views.py

```
def position_list_view(request):
    all_objects = Position.objects.all()
    context = {
        'object_list' : all_objects
    }
    return render(request, "exec_list.html", context)
```

exec_list.html

```
{% for object.category in object_list %}

    <h3>{{ object.category }}</h3>
    <p>{{ object.title }}</p>


{% endfor %}
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)

```
{% regroup object_list by category as category_list %}

<ul>
    {% for category in category_list %}
        <li>{{ category.grouper }}
            <ul>
            {% for position in category.list %}
                <li>{{ position.title }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Started toying with regroup after posting this and this seems to be the best solution. Thank you.